# jQuery throw error in IE <= 10

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer, debugging, microsoft-edge

on my wordpress site I am using jQuery but when I want to debug my page in Internet Explorer Edge it isnt working.
When I open the IE developer console and set the Version to something lower to Edge the site gets paused and the following error occurs:

```
Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference
File: jquery.min.js, Line: 74, Column: 67
```

I`ve tried it with the build in jQuery Version of Wordpress, v1.11.3 and v2.1.4 but theres always the same error.
I've also read another answer and added the following meta tag to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But it still isn't working.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: what version of jquery is actually throwing?

Comment: probably related to a plugin or your custom code and not jQuery itself. Use development version to find out where in jQuery the actual error is thrown so you can work backwards. Set a breakpoint also